# Independent WooCommerce Logic - Including?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to leverage WooCommerece API in a seperate, independant PHP file? For example, I want to run a php script that will tally all the sales for the day. The file will reside in the WooCommerence folder but have no connection to the WordPress or WooCommerence install:

e.g. salesTally.php

```
<?php 
//How to include?
global $woocommerce, $post;

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

//Do Stuff To Order

?>
```

Comment: yes, just load wp-load.php into that file

Comment: Thanks silver. Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to silver.

Possible solution:

```
include_once('wp-load.php');
global $woocommerce;
//Search for complete wc_bookings, return a maximum of 200
$orders = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'   => 'wc_booking',
        'post_status' =>  'complete',
        'posts_per_page' => 200
) );

print_r($orders);
```